# タグを付与する基準 (具体例: testing タグについて)

Tags: 討議, タグ

testing のタグを見ていたところ、たとえば python, ruby-on-rails, java, ocaml, javascript などもろもろのテストに関する質問が、このタグにひもづいていました。

なので、例えば、このタグをフォローした人がいたとしても、その人はおそらく幸せにならないだろうなと思い、各言語・(テスト)フレームワークに特有の質問をしていた場合には、タグを付け替える・消すという作業を行っていました。

が、そうやって遡って整理していったところ、 [Meteor+mochaでテストが実行されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/152/754) の質問で、モデーレータさんによって javascript (のテストライブラリである[mocha](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha))のテスト特有の質問が testing にタグ付けされていて、何が正しいのかわからなくなりました。

タグとは、それ単体ではフォローしたり、検索するには十分に細くなってはいなくても、対象の問題のある側面についての整理が行えているのならば、付与してしまうのがよい、ということでしょうか。。？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そもそも前提の考えとして、
タグとは特定の問題に対してグループ付けをし検索をしやすくすることだと思っております。

例に挙がっている`testing`のタグの説明には下記のようにあります。

> testing（ソフトウェアテスト）は、コンピュータのプログラムを実行し、正しく動作するか、目標とした品質に到達しているか、意図しない動作をしないかどうかを確認する作業のことである。

`testing`タグから検索で飛んでくる人は
　・試験方法自体を模索している
　・○○言語の試験での問題の解決方法を探している
　・試験についての考え方について知りたい
などが考えられます。

ここでタグの用途を考えると
「タグ自体について調べたい」だけではなくて、
「特定の言語とAND検索を行い質問を絞り込む」タグもありなのではないかと考えました。

私は例に挙がっているタグで見ると、わざわざ削除する必要は無いかなぁと感じます。

Comment: 例えば`データベース設計`なども`postgresql`か`mysql`と組み合わせることで絞れるような気もします。